why i can't get my subscriptions using react-native-iap
I created one subscriptoin on my App Store Connect
enter image description here
And tried to get this subscription in my code like this
  const { connected, getSubscriptions } = useIAP()

  const subSkus = ['Basic']

  const handleGetSubscriptions = async () => {
    try {
      if (connected) {
        const subs = await getSubscriptions({ skus: subSkus })

        console.log(subs, 'subs')
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error in handleGetSubscriptions:', error)
    }
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    handleGetSubscriptions()
  }, [connected])


but in console i see undefined
how i can fix this?
if you need more info tell me about this!

For this I suggest you to log any errors that occur during the getSubscriptions call to understand why subs might be undefined so please replace your code with the given code.
const { connected, getSubscriptions } = useIAP();
const subSkus = ['Basic'];

const handleGetSubscriptions = async () => {
  try {
    if ( connected ) {
      const subs = await getSubscriptions({ skus: subSkus });

      console.log('Subscription response:', subs); // Log the entire response to see what's returned

      if ( subs ) {
        console.log( 'Subscriptions fetched successfully:', subs );
      } else {
        console.log( 'No subscriptions fetched or empty response' );
      }
    } else {
      console.log( 'Not connected to IAP service' );
    }
  } catch ( error ) {
    console.error( 'Error in handleGetSubscriptions:', error );
  }
};

React.useEffect(() => {
  handleGetSubscriptions();
}, [connected]);

Please let me know if this helps.
